# Instantiating PrismaClient with Next.js in production

Tags: prisma

Prisma documentation recommends to instantiate Prisma Client as below to avoid infamous `Already 10 Prisma Clients are actively running` issue;

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

declare global {
  // allow global `var` declarations
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-var
  var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined
}

export const prisma =
  global.prisma ||
  new PrismaClient({
    log: ['query'],
  })

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') global.prisma = prisma
```

it runs OK in dev environment. What I need to ask, do I need this `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'` check? Should I instantiate Prisma Client in production differently?

Comment: Useful for me: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/other/troubleshooting-orm/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no harm in keeping the check. Your `NODE_ENV` will be production so the condition won't match and PrismaClient will not be assigned to `global` variable.

There isn't going to be hot reloading in the production environment so there's no need of reusing the same `PrismaClient`